# Hidden checkbox required to be checked even when hidden

Tags: html, checkbox, display, hidden

I’m kinda of stuck.

I’m using html5 required for a very simple validation, and I have a checkbox that only shows up if you meet some conditions. You then have to agree with terms and check the checkbox.

The problem is when you don’t hit conditions and checkbox reminds hidden then its not posible to submit. It should only be required if you see it.

```
.terms{
display: none;
}

<form>

<p><input class="terms" type="checkbox" id="checkId" required>Terms & Conditions</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Use visibility hidden, not display none. Visibility: hidden will allow the checkbox to still be on the page, just invisible. Display: none hides it

Comment: The attribute `required` might be the problem? Maybe you need to do the validation with JavaScript only or set this attribute conditionally? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required

Comment: I've set .terms{ visibility: hidden; } in this small code in my question and still cant submit.

Comment: How do you examine your terms and conditions? Is JS an option? If yes provide us your js code please, where ever you are setting conditions you can remove or add ```required ```

Comment: To post the value of the checkbox you have to set it to checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
<form>
<p><input class="terms" type="checkbox" id="checkId" name="checkId" checked style="visibility: hidden;">Terms & Conditions</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />

</form>
```